# How to get Facebook User id, email, picture.type (large) in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

I try to get user `id, email, picture.type(large),updated_time` from `Facebook SDK`, I successfully get all of them but I didn't get **picture** gives me:

> Error Cannot call value of non-function type 'Any?!'

My clear codes under below.

```
    import UIKit
    import Foundation
    
    class LoginViewController : UIViewController, FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate {
       private var fromLogin = [Login]()
       @IBOutlet weak var loginButton : FBSDKLoginButton!
        
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
             // Check Session
            if let token = FBSDKAccessToken.current(){
                print(token.tokenString! as Any)
                self.fetchProfile()
            }

            loginButton.delegate = self
            loginButton.readPermissions = ["email", "public_profile"]
    }

    // Get Profile
    func fetchProfile() {
        print("fetch profile")
        
        // Create facebook graph with fields
         FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields":"id, name, email, picture.type(large), updated_time"]).start { (connection, result, error) in
            
            // check error
            if error != nil {
                // error happen
                print("Failed to start graph request: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
            
            if let userDict = result as? NSDictionary {
                let name = userDict["name"] as? String
                let id = userDict["id"] as? String
                let email = userDict["email"] as? String

                // HERE GIVES ERROR I DIDNT GET PICTURE WITH STRING    
                let userPicture = userDict.objectForKey("picture")?.objectForKey("data")?.objectForKey("url") as String

                print(userPicture)
                print(name as Any)
                print(id as Any)
                print(email as Any)
        }
    }
}

// Delegate Method
func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWith result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: Error!){
    // check error
    if error != nil {
        // error happen
        print(error?.localizedDescription as Any)
        return
    }
    
    print("Successfull login in with facebook...")
    fetchProfile()
}

func loginButtonDidLogOut(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!){
    print("Log Out")
}
```

This line gives error;

> let userPicture = userDict.objectForKey("picture")?.objectForKey("data")?.objectForKey("url") as String

Also picture object json data example here;

```
 picture =     {
        data =         {
            "is_silhouette" = 0;
            url = "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p200x200/14067524_9513823423422249533237851_n.jpg?oh=88eb9b80abbb2342346c01de298&oe=58C5138B";
        };
    };
```

I'm using `Xcode 8.1` and `Swift 3.0`

Comment: Try the following answer

Comment: @User511 my codes working just need get picture true string code

Comment: It has complete code. And its working for me.

Comment: @User511 where is userPicture string ? u doing only print all result

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 bro ty worked perfectly can you give answer ? i will approve it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This requires simple parsing .. "picture" is Dictionary and so is "data". so something like below works for you

```
guard let userDict = result as? [String:Any] else { return }

let name  = userDict["name"] as? String
let id    = userDict["id"] as? String
let email = userDict["email"] as? String

if let picture = userDict["picture"] as? [String:Any] ,  
   let imgData = picture["data"] as? [String:Any] ,   
   let imgUrl = imgData["url"] as? String {   
      print(imgUrl)   
}
```

Comment: @El Captain v2.0 Thank you man worked perfectly on Xcode 8.1 and Swift 3.0

Answer (score 1):

Replace this

```
 FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields":"id, name, email, picture.type(large), updated_time"]).start { (connection, result, error) in
```

with

```
FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields":"id, name, email, picture.width(500).height(500), updated_time"]).start { (connection, result, error) in
```

Then check this

```
if let imageUrl = ((dictData.value(forKey: "picture") as? NSDictionary)?.value(forKey: "data") as? NSDictionary)?.value(forKey: "url") as? NSString
                                    {
                                        Facebook.imagesArr.add(imageUrl)
                                        print("Pictureasd:",Facebook.imagesArr)
                                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWith result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: Error!)
    {
        FBSDKGraphRequest.init(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields":"first_name, last_name, picture.type(large)"]).start { (connection, result, error) -> Void in

            let strFirstName: String = (result.object(forKey: "first_name") as? String)!
            let strLastName: String = (result.object(forKey: "last_name") as? String)!
            let strPictureURL: String = (result.object(forKey: "picture")?.object(forKey: "data")?.object(forKey: "url") as? String)!

            self.lblName.text = "Welcome, \(strFirstName) \(strLastName)"
            self.ivUserProfileImage.image = UIImage(data: try! Data(contentsOf: URL(string: strPictureURL)!))
        }
    }
```